# Converting double to string with a return

Tags: java, string, double

I'm trying to return a double value as a string but am unsure of how to get my method to work:

```
public String getTestGauge()  
{
  double.toString(getTestGauge);
  return test / 8;
}
```

The 8 is there because I am returning this as a fraction in eighths and assume by dividing test by 8 will give me a % which I then will be rounding to the nearest integer, thus being a fraction in eighths.

EDIT: My question isn't about how my code looks necessarily, it's about how to convert a double to a string in this.

Comment: It looks like there are some mistakes in your code. Where is the variable `test` declared?

Comment: It's declared elsewhere in my code. I'm just curious about how to convert this from a double to a string.

Comment: What language?  You should add a tag

Comment: The double.toString line is complete nonsense and shouldn't even compile. Even if it did compile, it serves no purpose, as you aren't using the value it returns in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public String getTestGauge(){
     return String.valueOf(<yourdouble>);
}
```

--> this is prettier

```
return (new Double(<yourdouble>).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing at what it is you're trying to accomplish, since the code you provided is gibberish, but this may be what you are looking for:

```
public String getTestGauge() {
   return Double.toString(test / 8);
}
```